# CakePHP: joins inside contain

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

As the title says, I'm having troubles with joins in my find-query, with errors appearing like:

```
  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given [CORE/cake/libs/model/behaviors/containable.php, line 301]
```

I've tried adding `joins` to the array over there, but it didn't change anything.

These are the options I'm passing to the find method.

```
$options = array(
   'contain' => array(
      'Answer' => array(
         'conditions' => array('Answer.type' => 'answer'),
         'joins' => array(
            $this->votesJoin()
         ),
         'Comment' => array(
            'conditions' => array('Comment.type' => 'comment'),
            'joins' => array(
               $this->votesJoin()
            )
         )
      ),
      'Comment' => array(
         'conditions' => array('Comment.type' => 'comment'),
         'joins' => array(
            $this->votesJoin()
         )
      ),
      'User',
      'Tag' => array()
   ),
   'joins' => array(
      $this->votesJoin()
   ),
   'conditions' => array(
      'Question.id' => $id
   )
);

return $this->find('first', $options);
```

with `votesJoin()` returning the following array.

```
(
   [table] => (SELECT Vote.node_id, SUM(value) as total FROM votes AS `Vote`   WHERE 1 = 1  GROUP BY `Vote`.`node_id`  )
   [alias] => Vote
   [conditions] => Vote.node_id = Question.id
)
```

What I'm trying to do:
Each user can up/downvote a node (question/answer/comment). With the join I'm trying to add the sum of those votes.
[database http://github.com/navale/QA/wiki/img/datamodel.png](http://github.com/navale/QA/wiki/img/datamodel.png)

Comment: so you want to retrieve: the question, the comments on the question, the answers, the comments on the answers, and in the sum of votes for all those elements.. and everything in one single query.. seems quite ambitious to me =P

Comment: Nah, I know I'm gonna need different queries for the question, answers and comments, but I *would* to join the votes to those queries...

Comment: Your `$this->votesJoin()` returns an array? Then you shouldn't wrap it in one more array.

Comment: Also, you probably should rename your tables according to [Cake conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions), which will save you some hair.

Comment: The [CakePHP website](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables) also puts each join in an array ;)

Comment: @Ixa, which ones do you mean? only question_views, or also split up the nodes-table?

Answer (score 1):

You should use "joins" only for things that can't be done with Cake model relationship and Containable. I don't know the details of your database, but I think the find operation can be simplified. Why don't you post the schema for these tables on here?

try this:

> ```
> $options = array(
> 'contain' => array(
>   'Answer' => array(
>      'conditions' => array('Answer.type' => 'answer'),
>      'Vote' => array(
>         'fields' => array('SUM(Vote.value)'),
>         'group'  => array('Vote.parent_id')
>      ),
>      'Comment' => array(
>         'conditions' => array('Comment.type' => 'comment'),
>         'Vote' => array(
>                         'fields' => array('SUM(Vote.value)'),
>                         'group'  => array('Vote.parent_id')
>                  )
>      )
>   ),
>   'Comment' => array(
>      'conditions' => array('Comment.type' => 'comment'),
>      'Vote' => array(
>         'fields' => array('SUM(Vote.value)'),
>         'group'  => array('Vote.parent_id')
>      )
>   ),
>   'User',
>   'Tag' => array()
> ```
>
> ),
>      'conditions' => array(
>         'Question.id' => $id
>      )
>   );

You get the Vote sum value for each answer, comment, and comment for answer. (You might need to add 'hasMany' Vote in the Node model if you haven't done that yet)

If instead you want to get one single total sum of Vote for the question, then I'd suggest:
get the list of the answers and comments of the question:

> $lvl1 = find('list','fields'=>array('id'),'conditions'=>array('Node.parent_id'=>$id))

then get list of the comments of the answers

> $lvl2 = find('list','fields'=>array('id'),'conditions'=>array('Node.parent_id'=>$lvl1))

then just combine the 2 array then do a sum over that.

Comment: Added the schema, anything else you'd like to know?

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. Containable sees the 'group' as a field... I think I'll just get the ID's of all comments and answers found, and just do a seperate vote find on that array... Thanks for your help though ;)

Comment: really? that's weird: http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/10/06/top-10-things-to-look-forward-to-in-cakephp-1-3/